# Openvpn connect to server's lan

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, openvpn

Could somebody help me because I do not understand what's happening?
I setupped openvpn server on windows 10 successfully and everything is alright with it. I can ping computers on server side lan with vpn clients, but I can't understand how because I didn't set anything on my router's static route table. Could somebody explain me, that how is this possible? How the computers know on the server side lan where they have to send back the packets?

Comment: More than likely "routing" and/or "dnat" and your VPN server routing accordingly when the packets hit it.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, your router shouldn't actually need any routes on the router itself. the OVPN server is acting as a virtual router for remote VPN clients to contact the LAN. the only routes required are on the VPN client systems, to send traffic destined for the remote lan into the tunnel. you do need a dnat (port forward) rule to send traffic from the public side of the router to the OVPN server, but other than that, the gateway router of the remote lan doesn't really need any special routes.